# Plot Count/frequency of tweets for word by month

Tags: r, twitter, plot, count

I have connected R to Twitter and am scraping using the `searchTwitter` function in R, and cleaning the resultant data for punctuation, lowercase, etc. Now I'm trying to do the following:

- *count* the number of tweets with the word "*auction*" that have been tweeted per month since *Jan 2015* until the end of July 2015.
- Plot the count in a simple bar chart (`x-axis - month`; `y-axis - number of tweets`).

I'd like to reuse this for *retweets*, *mentions*, *replies* and *favorites*.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
#load the packages into R
>library(twitteR)
>library(plyr)
>library(ggplot2)    

# Register an application (API) at https://apps.twitter.com/
# Look up the API key and create a token – you need for both the key and the secret
# Assign the keys to variables and use the authorization
api_key <- “your API key from twitter”
api_secret <- “your Secret key from twitter”
access_token <- “you Access Token from twitter”
access_token_secret <- “you Access Token Secret key from twitter”
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
```

> [1](https://www.miskatonic.org/2012/10/21/accessyul-tweets-chart/) "Using direct authentication"
>     Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
>       1: Yes
>       2: No
>       # Type 1 and press Enter
>       Selection: 1

```
auctiontweets <- searchTwitter("auction", since = "2015-01-01", until = "2015-08-03", n=1000)
```

However, I'm having trouble creating a data frame, getting the following error:

```
tweet.dataframe <- data.frame(searchTwitter("action", since = "2015-01-01", until = "2015-08-03", n=3000))
```

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :
>       cannot coerce class "structure("status", package = "twitteR")" to a data.frame

I found code on how to plot users by hour; but wasn't able to modify it so that it works for tweets with a specific word (i.e. 'auction') per month:

```
yultweets <- searchTwitter("#accessyul", n=1500)
y <- twListToDF(yultweets)
y$created <- as.POSIXct(format(y$created, tz="America/Montreal"))
yply <- ddply(y, .var = "screenName", .fun = function(x) {return(subset(x,     
created %in% min(created), select = c(screenName,created)))})
yplytime <- arrange(yply,-desc(created))
y$screenName=factor(y$screenName, levels = yplytime$screenName)
ggplot(y) + geom_point(aes(x=created,y=screenName)) + ylab("Twitter username") + xlab("Time")
```

The source can be found [here](https://www.miskatonic.org/2012/10/21/accessyul-tweets-chart/).

Comment: Please post your current code, along with the code you've written to try to achieve this.

Comment: I added code, thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide even a small piece of your data that we could cope with, my answer might superficial.

```
library(stringi); library(dplyr); library(SciencesPo)

  df <- data.frame(tweets = c("blah, blah, Blah, auction","blah, auction", "blah, blah", "this auction, blah", "today"), date=c('2015-07-01','2015-06-01','2015-05-01','2015-07-31','2015-05-01'))
  > df
                         tweets       date
    1 blah, blah, Blah, auction 2015-07-01
    2             blah, auction 2015-06-01
    3                blah, blah 2015-05-01
    4        this auction, blah 2015-07-31
    5                     today 2015-05-01

 filter = "auction"

> df$n <- vapply(df$tweets, function(x) sum(stri_count_fixed(x, filter)), 1L)
> df
                     tweets       date n
1 blah, blah, Blah, auction 2015-07-01 1
2             blah, auction 2015-06-01 1
3                blah, blah 2015-05-01 0
4        this auction, blah 2015-07-31 1
5                     today 2015-05-01 0
```

Then, the only thing is to summarise:

```
 df %>% group_by(month=format(as.Date(date),format="%m")) %>% summarize(freq=sum(n)) 
%>%ungroup() -> df2

> df2
    Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

      month freq
    1    05 0
    2    06 1
    3    07 2
    >
```

Voilà! Bonus, plot it as `ggplot(df2, aes(x=month, y=freq)) + geom_line() + theme_pub()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer despite my awfully worded question *total noob alarm* (I added code!) I see that I cannot use the data.frame function and searchTwitter function together; would you recommend I save the twitter data as a csv and then create a dataframe out of it or could I use df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l), nrow=3000, byrow=T))?

Comment: you can use as the way works best for you. Given that I hadn't full information, I offered a solution in mind your data as a data frame. You can transform you data as such or then modify the vapply syntax, so can deal with data as list. it's up to you.